# Primus: both GPUs are detected. Cuda works but OpenGl doesn't

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, opengl, cuda

Context: Kubuntu 14.04, Gigabyte p3 Laptop with two graphic cards :

```
 *-display               
   description: 3D controller
   product: GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a2
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: irq:16 memory:f5000000-f5ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f6000000-f607ffff

*-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 06
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:49 memory:f6400000-f67fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

Cuda 8.0 needed the lastest driver for the Nvidia card, so I installed it from Nvidia's site and then installed Cuda 8.0 from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads). Now, cuda works. But, when I run **glxinfo**, I get

```
name of display: :0
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
```

etc. If you look at the output of lshw previously shown, it says that display 0 is the NVIDIA card. I tried installing bumblbee, but it doesn't seem to work well on 14.04 with recent drivers (boot to black screen, login loop, etc.). In the best case OpenGL worked but then I lost Cuda. So, any clarifications on those questions will be extermely welcome:

- Why do openGL programs fail when the GPU is correctly identified?
- Is there a way to force openGl programs to use display 1 (the intel card)?

**Edit:**
   using the Debian package from NVIDIA's site instead of their *.run script fixes that problem. However, I still do not understand why and how. Is this a bug in their script?